# Pass component props for use in styled-components GlobalStyle

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, styled-components

I think I might be going about this in the completely wrong way, so any suggestions to do this better would be great!

I have a modal component.  When it's visible, I'd like a `GlobalStyle` for `html { overflow: hidden }` to prevent the page from scrolling.

**Here's my code:**
*I've removed as much useless code as I can*

**Modal.jsx:**

```
export const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  html {

    overflow: ${props => {
        const { visible } = props;

        console.log(props); // This logs my theme props?

        if (visible === true) {
            return "hidden";
        }
        return "auto";
    }}
}
`;

function Component({ ...props }) {
    const {
        visible
    } = props;

    return ( <Modal visible={visible} /> );
}
```

**App.jsx** *GlobalStyle is imported from Modal*

```
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { GlobalStyle } from "../presentation/modal/modal";
import Controller from "./controller";

const theme = {
    //theme stuff
};

const App = props => {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <React.Fragment>
                <GlobalStyle />
                <Controller {...props} />
            </React.Fragment>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
};

export default App;
```

So, I either need my GlobalStyle to know when visible is true or false, or I need a better way to achieve this?  Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Could be worth mentioning that I do have a redux store that handles my state?  Can this be used elsewhere to achieve this?  Potentially moving the `GlobalStyle` out of my component?

**Inside Modal.jsx**

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    visible: state.modalReducer.visible
});
```

Comment: I think you are on the right track when you thought of state to solve the problem. I would use the local state of the app component to store the boolean and update it as needed.

Comment: Does passing redux state to `<GlobalStyle />` not work for you?

Comment: @BrianLe how do you mean, sorry?

Comment: Does this not work for u: `<GlobalStyle visible={visible} />`?

Comment: @BrianLe So, I've imported my redux store into `App.jsx` and I'm passing visible like this: `const { modalReducer } = store.getState(); / <GlobalStyle visible={modalReducer.visible} />`.  This works on the inital load and the props can be seen correctly within the component, but when that state updates (Modal becomes visible), it still doesn't update html styling

Comment: Why would you want to change `GlobalStyle` and not styling the modal?

Comment: Also, it's a good opportunity to make a minimal working example in some sandbox-like codesandbox.

Comment: why not use `connect`?